# count based on nested key mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can i count based on xTag key is on doc
I tried this but it does not provide me actual count

```
db.collection.find({
  "products.xTag": {
    $exists: false
  }
}).count();
```

when you run with `$exist:true` i would expect result 1

When you run with `$exist:false` i would expect result 3

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_gf7RzGc8oB

Structure:

```
[
 {
   "item": 1,
   "products": [
     {
       "name": "xyz",
       "xTag": 32423
     },
     {
       "name": "abc"
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "item": 2,
   "products": [
     {
       "name": "bob",
       
     },
     {
       "name": "foo"
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with find(), You can use [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/),

- `$unwind` deconstruct `products` array
- `$match` your condition
- `$count` total documents

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  { $match: { "products.xTag": { $exists: false } } },
  { $count: "count" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ctn_3NjCLne)